# jquery backbone click event does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, parse-platform

Im doing almost the exact same with group and child views as this [example](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/12-listening-to-dom-events-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js/) does with *App.views.people* and with *App.views.person*. I put a button into the li element in the child and it does not fire when clicked.

What i see debugging...

When i create the child views **new RoleRoleView({** , the event hash *"click .first"* is bound to the view OK and it looks like the events are defined ok on the view. I don't know where they end up when searched for by Jqry when the actual click occurs.  But when i debug the click on the button and look into JQuery code for the dispatch of the event to the registered handers, there is nothing in the Queue for Jquery handlers on a click that occured in the "li" tag...

In other words, the jQuery code below has nothing in the handlerQueues to process when i click on the button "Del" class="first".

--EDIT--
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82EvA/68/) using static collections instead of parse.com backend WORKS ok. 
But when i hook up the parse cloud, the event on line 29 of the fiddle does not fire...

```
  'click .rmgroup': 'rmagrp'
```

JS.20 for the entry in the event.Hash that jquery is not firing  ( "click .rmgroup"...

---

JQ 2.03 Dispatch ( DEBUG - i think the handlerQueue is empty for a click on Del and it should not be )

```
    // Determine handlers
    handlerQueue = jQuery.event.handlers.call(this, event, handlers);

    // Run delegates first; they may want to stop propagation beneath us
    i = 0;
    while ((matched = handlerQueue[i++]) && !event.isPropagationStopped()) {
        event.currentTarget = matched.elem;

        j = 0;
        while ((handleObj = matched.handlers[j++]) && !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()) {

            // Triggered event must either 1) have no namespace, or
            // 2) have namespace(s) a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
            if (!event.namespace_re || event.namespace_re.test(handleObj.namespace)) {

                event.handleObj = handleObj;
                event.data = handleObj.data;

                ret = ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler)
                .apply(matched.elem, args);

                if (ret !== undefined) {
                    if ((event.result = ret) === false) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my Code is below

```
var PostView = Parse.View.extend({

tagName:  "li",
template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
events: {
  "click .relation" : "userrelation",
  "click .post-content" : "userrelation",
  "click .innrrole" : "rolerelation"
},
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
},

render: function() {
  $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  return this;
},


rolerelation: function() {
if(this.model.get("ACL").getWriteAccess(Parse.User.current())){
        var relation = this.model.relation("roles");
```

...

```
    $("#post-list").empty();
var roleView = new ManageRolesView({collection: mroles, role:role, rolename:rolename, model:Post});
            });         
    } else alert("Update by group owner only ");
}
```

});

```
var ManageRolesView = Parse.View.extend({

// Delegated events for creating new items, and clearing completed ones.
events: {
  "keypress #new-Role":  "createOnEnter"
},
el: ".content",
initialize: function(options) {
    //TODO fix callback     
    var self = this;
    var parentName = this.options.rolename;

    _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll',  'createOnEnter');
    this.$el.html(_.template($("#manage-roles-template").html()));
    this.$("#prole-info").html(this.options.rolename);  
    this.input = this.$("#new-Role");
    state.on("change", this.addAll(this.collection , this ));
    this.collection.bind('reset',     this.addAll);
    this.collection.bind('add',     this.addOne);
},  
addOne: function(Role) {
  var view = new RoleRoleView({model: Role});
  this.$("#role-list").append(view.render().el);
},
addAll: function(collection, filter) {

    this.$("#role-list").html("");     
    this.collection.each(this.addOne);      
},
createOnEnter: function(e) {
    ...      
this.input.val(''); 
}       
});


    //ROLE  ROLE VIEW
    var RoleRoleView = Parse.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template($('#role-template').html()), 
    events: {
        "click .first" : "rmagrp" ** this event does not fire **
        },

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'rmagrp');
    },

    rmagrp: function() {
        console.log("CLK on A tag");
        alert("bugout");

    },    
    render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    }        
});
```

Poster
    -->
    
  </script> -->

```
<div id="postapp">
  <div class="title">


    <h2><img src='images/ebook.jpg' style="vertical-align:middle" width="40" height="40"   />
        <label style="padding:5px 5px 5px 25px;">Tell Me Stories - Groups</label>

    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Templates -->

<script type="text/template" id="login-template">
  <header id="header"></header>
  <div class="login">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button>Log In</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="manage-posts-template">

  <div id="user-info">

    Signed in as <%= Parse.User.current().get("username") %> <a href="#" class="log-out">Log out</a>
  </div>

  <div class="section">

    <header id="header">
      <input id="new-Post" placeholder=" <%= input_label %> " type="text" />
    </header>

    <div id="main">          
      <ul id="post-list">
        <img src='images/spinner.gif' class='spinner' />
      </ul>
    </div>        
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="manage-roles-template">

        <p id=prole-info/>                                   

  <div class="section">     
    <header id="header">                        
      <input id="new-Role" placeholder="Type-Role-Name-here:" type="text" />                    
    </header>

    <div id="role-main">          
      <ul id="role-list">
        <img src='images/spinner.gif' class='spinner' />
      </ul>
    </div>
       <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer">

        <a href="" >Home</a>

  </footer>
</script>    

<script type="text/template" id="manage-users-template">
<div class="section">
    <header >
        <p id=prole-info/>                                   
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="section">     
    <header id="header">                        
      <input id="new-User" placeholder="Type-Group-Members-here:" type="text" />                    
    </header>

    <div id="user-main">          
      <ul id="user-list">
        <img src='images/spinner.gif' class='spinner' />
      </ul>
    </div>
           <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer">

        <a href="" >Home</a>

  </footer>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">

<div class="view">
<a href="#" class="relation">
<img src="images/user.png"  style="vertical-align:middle" width="40" height="40">
</a>    
  <label class="post-content"><%= name %></label>
<a href="#" class="innrrole">
<img src="images/group-sm.png"  style="vertical-align:middle" width="40" height="40">
</a>
  <button class="todo-destroy"></button>    
</div>

  </li>
</script>    

<script type="text/template" id="user-template">

<div class="user">  
  <label class="user-content"><%= name %></label>

</div>

  </li>
</script>

 <script type="text/template" id="role-template" >

<div class="role">  
  <label class="role-content"><%= name %></label>
<button class="first" >
   Del
</button>   
</div>



  </li>
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah I'll put on fiddle. Fwiw due to parse.com the io will not work but the full code will be there

Comment: fiddle is up.. see EDIT to OP. in fiddle, see JS line 20 and HTML line 21 for the event that does not fire.. Its not the exact same code as in the post but the fiddle will give the idea. No Parse.com token in fiddle without keys and a logon credential, but IM me and ill provide that if needed ...

Comment: That fiddle doesn't even render the views you are talking about...

Comment: not exactly the same code. However, it does work with the same view names appearing in the source in different locations. Im still working thru this with full debug of the jquery code surrounding the "Dispatch()" function .. The fiddle works but the production code does not hook up the events bound to RoleRoleView to the higher level DOM in a way that "jquery.Dispatch()" can locate the proper handler on the click event.